# Xperia mini 17i update Android 2.3 to 4.0

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates

I try update Android from 2.3 to 4, using tool `Sony PC Companion 2.1`.
Tool want terminate processes `wininit.exe` and `java.exe`.
I can't terminate this processes using Far manager and Task manager.
When I accept termination of processes by `Sony PC Companion 2.1`, my computer is restrted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer after Sony's PC Companion was first installed?

Comment: Did you see the source or file location of `wininit.exe and java.exe` it occurs to me that these files are virus files and you need to run some antivirus scan. The problem is these viruses use a regular windows process name and will be in another directory to cause confusion.
Running [MalwareBytes][1] may help. 

One more thing if you find `wininit.exe or java.exe` in other than `System32` folder you can delete it.


  [1]: https://www.malwarebytes.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can't terminate `wininit`.  If their installer is trying to do so then it's broken, or trying to install a rootkit by replacing system files in use by `wininit`.  Normally you should have an option to ignore the warning and it will simply need a reboot after the install (though given that it's warning about a system process, I wouldn't trust it as far as I could throw it).  Did you get the installer from Sony's official site?

Comment: When I connect phone to PC, Sony PC Companion 2.1 was automaticaly downloaded. Don't know source

Answer (score -3):

Did you see the source or file location of `wininit.exe and java.exe` it occurs to me that these files are virus files and you need to run some antivirus scan. The problem is these viruses use a regular windows process name and will be in another directory to cause confusion.
Running [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) may help.

One more thing if you find `wininit.exe or java.exe` in other than `System32` folder you can delete it.

Source : [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggpx9VAivvE)

**The best thing you can do for updation is trying in another virus free pc or removing the virus in your pc**

Comment: That is not an answer!

Comment: @t0mm13b is this okay? I dont know why it got two negative votes?

Comment: You obviously do not understand `winit.exe` or `java.exe` and brazenly label them as *viruses* I really do not know where you got this from as your answer is implying a completely lack of ignorance and knowledge on your part, and spreading FUD. Which is why your answer got downvoted !

Comment: @t0mm13b I know what is wininit.exe and java.exe as I am a windows user. But that is the technique most malware writers do. They use a regular windows process name and place it in another directory to cause confusion.

Comment: @t0mm13b https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggpx9VAivvE this video shows about wininit.exe virus